# Does ABAP replacement code correspond to SQL "replace" function

Tags: sql, abap

I have the following ABAP Code which I need to convert to SQL.

There is a function to replace empty spaces in SQL, but how do I apply it on this code?

```
data: s1 type string.
data: s2 type string.

s1 = SOURCE_FIELDS_RULE-MATNR.

CONDENSE s1 NO-GAPS.
s2 = s1+0(11).

RESULT = s2.
```

I had thought that:

```
select replace (Material, ' ', '');
```

could do this, but does it replace material numbers within its own field?

Comment: `replace` is also a valid function in OpenSQL (NetWeaver >7.50) but I'm not able to test it

Comment: "but does it replace material numbers within its own field?" - not clear what this means. Showing an example of the input data and desired result could help, not many people know ABAP.

Comment: Of course `replace` does replace into the same field. How else it can work?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to replace the empty spaces within the same field.
Input on the column Material looks like "A123 456 789 00" I want to have it stored as "A12345678900"

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do.

- If you want to just display the numbers somewhere, I advise using conversion exits like `CONVERSION_EXIT_MATN1_OUTPUT` etc.
- If you want to do that via (S)ALV, there are built-in features, that do the conversion for you. Read the docks.
- If you on a new system (≥7.4) better to use CDS View, because it can do anything you need and provide the data in the format you need, [there are many useful functions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abencds_f1_sql_functions_character.htm).
- You also can use ABAP SQL (aka OpenSQL) [`replace` function](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/20e66a2c75191014bac6a279955db665.html), but I'm not sure about versions.
- If you just want to fetch the data outside ABAP AS, simply use native SQL of your database.